# IntelliSense not listing members with VSCode Interactive Python code files

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense, interactive, pylance

In VSCode I use Python Interactive mode. I have a Python script open on one pane, and I execute the code in an interactive terminal open in another pane. IntelliSense works properly in the interactive pane - when I type "." after an object it lists all the object's members. But when I try the same thing in the script pane, it doesn't list the object's members.

Example below.

In the interactive pane, IntelliSense provides a full lists of the object's members:
[Interactive pane autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3em7.png)

But when I try the same thing in the Python script, it fails to lists the object's members after the cell has been run:
[Script pane autocomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9TqW.png)

I have tried the following things to fix this:

- Updated to the latest VScode, and uninstalled/reinstalled Microsoft's Python extension (no other extensions installed)
- In VScode settings, made sure the language server was using Pylance
- I am running inside a conda virtual environment, and I only have that one terminal running

My work-around is that, when I want to inspect a variable, I switch to the interactive pane in order to use its autocomplete, and then I switch back to the script pane to continue coding. Ideally, I should be able to see the full autocomplete in the script pane.

Please advise if there is a way to remedy this.

**Edit**: Minimal example below. IntelliSense problem seems specific to the Tensorflow/Keras object called `history` created below, hence I am importing Tensorflow to reproduce the problem:

```
#%% Execute this code cell in the Python interactive pane
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.Sequential([tf.keras.Input(1), tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='sgd')
history = model.fit([0, 1], [0, 1])
```

After running this, when I type `history.` (`history` plus trigger character `.`), IntelliSense should pop-up a small box listing all the members of the `history` object (e.g. `history.epoch`, `history.params`).

IntelliSense works in the Interactive pane: [IntelliSense invoked from Interactive pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRQNd.png)

But IntelliSense fails with "No suggestions." in the script pane: [After running cell, IntelliSense doesn't lists object's members when triggered in script pane](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYUKb.png)

Comment: Can you provide a minimal case to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I have now edited the question to include a minimal example. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The intellisense provided by Python and Pylance extensions is static type checking.

Obviously, the intellisense you need must be obtained after running the model, which is not achievable for intellisense.

The solution you have already mentioned is to use **an interactive window** to run code cells to obtain intellisense. Another method is similar to this one, you can use `.ipynb` file which is similar to interactive window. You can get the prompt after running the code cell.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am already doing as you've described. I first run the code block, and *then* I try accessing the member list of `history` (even though I show it all in the same code cell, I run the code first). Based on the screenshot you've shown, `history.` works in an `ipynb` file. However, it does not work in Python interactive mode where I have a script + interactive pane open. I don't see why, when `history` is created, I can access it's members in the interactive pane, and in an `ipynb` file, but the script pane IntelliSense fails to access its members. Seems like a subtle bug.

Comment: As I mentioned, Pylance statically analyzed and prompted, which means that even if you run it in the `.py` file, Pylance cannot obtain dynamic information. This goes beyond the functionality of intellisense. You can use jupyter or interacitve to continue.

Comment: But it works for `model` some and other variables I've tried. It seems like it's only failing with `history`. I don't see the distinction - i.e. why it fails for `history` but works for other variables. Could you please clarify?

Comment: @some3128 `history` here is a **History** object which was returned by method `fit()`. You can see that history was recognized as any type if you hover your mouse on history. Because intellisense cannot got this information because this goes beyond the functionality of intellisense. However, `model` can be recognize as sequential correctly because it was static type checking.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I'd find it useful to have IntelliSense function in the more comprehensive notebook-like way when using Python scripts in Interactive mode. I've marked your answer as Accepted.